# In terminal Emacs, is it possible to increase the spacing between Menu Bar items?

Tags: terminal-emacs, menu-bar, menus

[image: Example menu bar in terminal]

To me, the way the menu bar is displayed in the terminal (with only a single space between items) makes it look like a run-on sentence.

Is it possible to make the menu bar display with e.g. 3 spaces between items?